# how to do pattern matching of string in java?

Tags: java, android, string, pattern-matching

In my app I am getting some response from server. The time format I get is `"PT10H2M1S","PT1H2S","PT0S" etc`. If `H` is present in the string, I have to take the digits before that as **hours**. If `M` is present in the string, I have to take the digit before that as **minutes**. If `S` is present in the string I have to take the digit before that as **seconds**. How do I do it?

Comment: You can use split function of String.

Comment: Joda time could be helpful here: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html#parse(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static Pattern p = Pattern.compile("PT(?:([0-9]+)H)?(?:([0-9]+)M)?(?:([0-9]+)S)?");

static void parse(String s){
  Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
  m.find();
  String hh = m.group(1);
  String mm = m.group(2);
  String ss = m.group(3);
  System.out.println("s="+s+" hh="+hh+" mm="+mm+" ss="+ss);
}
```

Comment: Would you please add some explanation to the regexp?

Comment: please refer to the javadoc http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes.

```
String hours;
String mins;
String secs;
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)H|(\\d+)M|(\\d+)S");
while(m.find())
{
 hours = m.group(1);
 mins = m.group(2);
 secs = m.group(3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)H|(\\d+)M|(\\d+)S");
```

and you need a jude of `string` maybe the length of `string` or `contains ("M")`and `contains ("H")`……

Answer (score 0):

getting hour

```
public String getHour(String time)
{
    String hourString[] = time.split("H");
    String[] hour = hourString[0].split("T");
    return hour[1];
}
```

getting minute

```
public String getMinute(String time)
{
    String minuteString[] = time.split("M");
    String spitedMinute[] = null;
    String finalMinute[] = null;
    //check if H available
    if(minuteString[0].contains("H"))
    {
        spitedMinute = minuteString[0].split("H");
        finalMinute = spitedMinute[1].split("M");
        return finalMinute[0];
    }
    else
    {
        finalMinute = minuteString[0].split("T");
    }

    return finalMinute[1];

}
```

getting second

```
public String getSecond(String time)
{
    String spitedMinute[];
    String Second[];

    String spitedHour[];
    String splitedSecondString;
    String timeData[];
    if(time.contains("M"))
    {
        spitedMinute = time.split("M");
        Second = spitedMinute[1].split("S");
    }
    else if(time.contains("H"))
    {
        spitedHour = time.split("H");
        splitedSecondString = spitedHour[1];

        if(splitedSecondString.contains("M"))
        {
            spitedMinute = splitedSecondString.split("M");
            Second = spitedMinute[1].split("S");
        }
        else
        {
            Second = spitedHour[1].split("S");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        timeData = time.split("S");
        Second = timeData[0].split("T");
        return Second[1];
    }

    return Second[0];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
    String s = "PT1H22M18S";
    int hIndex = s.indexOf('H');
    int mIndex = s.indexOf('M');
    int sIndex = s.indexOf('S');

    String hours="",mintues="",seconds="";

    if (hIndex > 0) {
        hours = s.substring(2, hIndex);
    }
    if (mIndex > 0) {
        if (hIndex > 0) {
            mintues= s.substring((hIndex + 1), mIndex);
        } else {
            mintues= s.substring(2, mIndex);
        }
    }
    if (sIndex > 0) {
        if (mIndex > 0) {
            seconds= s.substring((mIndex + 1), sIndex);
        } else {
            if (hIndex > 0) {
                seconds= s.substring((hIndex + 1), sIndex);
            } else {
                seconds= s.substring(2, sIndex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: wrong answer. Your case wont work if M is not present and H & S is present, then (mIndex + 1) wont take you to Seconds value. Same in case of minutes when H is not present.